# Save state in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, savestate

I'm currently writing an app that displays a list of movies using a recyclerview. I have a bottom navigation bar(trending, search and favorites) with several fragments. I'm trying to save the state of each fragment(the checkbox in it, its position, etc) but it's not working

Below is my viewmodel. I'm retrieving several list of movies(trending movies, action movies, etc) as you can see I'm trying to save the state of trending movies but it's not working and I don't know why.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

MoviesListViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.moviesapp.ui

import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesRepository
import com.example.moviesapp.network.MoviesResults
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

const val DEFAULT_QUERY = " "
const val ACTION_MOVIES = "moviesAction"
const val COMEDY_MOVIES = "moviesComedy"
const val HORROR_MOVIES = "moviesHorror"
const val ROMANCE_MOVIES = "moviesRomance"
const val SCIFI_MOVIES = "moviesScifi"
const val TRENDING_MOVIES = "moviesTrending"


enum class MovieApiStatus {LOADING, ERROR, DONE}


@HiltViewModel
class MoviesListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MoviesRepository,
    private val state: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {

       private val _moviesAction = state.getLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>(ACTION_MOVIES)
       val moviesAction: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesAction

       private val _moviesComedy = state.getLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>(COMEDY_MOVIES)
       val moviesComedy: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesComedy

       private val _moviesHorror = state.getLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>(HORROR_MOVIES)
       val moviesHorror: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesHorror

       private val _moviesRomance = state.getLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>(ROMANCE_MOVIES)
       val moviesRomance: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesRomance

       private val _moviesScifi = state.getLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>>(SCIFI_MOVIES)
       val moviesScifi: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesScifi

    private val _moviesTrending: MutableLiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = state.getLiveData(MOVIES_TRENDING, arrayListOf())
    val moviesTrending: LiveData<List<MoviesResults.Movies>> = _moviesTrending

    private val _networkState = MutableLiveData<MovieApiStatus>()
    val networkState: LiveData<MovieApiStatus> = _networkState





    init {
        getMovies()

    }




 fun getAction() {
     viewModelScope.launch {
         _moviesAction.value = repository.getActionMovies()
     }
 }

     fun getComedy() {
         viewModelScope.launch {
             _moviesComedy.value = repository.getComedyMovies()

         }

     }

    fun getHorror() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _moviesHorror.value = repository.getHorrorMovies()
        }

    }
    fun getRomance() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _moviesRomance.value = repository.getRomanceMovies()
        }

    }

    fun getScifi() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _moviesScifi.value = repository.getScifiMovies()

        }

    }

    fun getTrending() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _moviesTrending.value = repository.getTrendingMovies()
        }

    }

    fun saveTrendingMovie(moviesTrending: List<MoviesResults.Movies>) {
        state.set(MOVIES_TRENDING, moviesTrending)

    }

    fun getTrendingMovies(): List<MoviesResults.Movies> {
        return state.get(MOVIES_TRENDING) ?: emptyList()

    }















    private var currentQuery = MutableLiveData(DEFAULT_QUERY)







     val movies = currentQuery.switchMap {
            queryString ->
       liveData {
           emit(repository.getSearchResults(queryString))
       }
   }

    fun searchMovies(query: String) {

    currentQuery.value = query

    }

    private fun getMovies() {
        viewModelScope. launch {
            _networkState.value = MovieApiStatus.LOADING
            try {
                _networkState.value = MovieApiStatus.DONE
            }
            catch (e: Exception) {
                _networkState.value = MovieApiStatus.ERROR

            }

        }

    }

    companion object {
        private val MOVIES_TRENDING="moviesTrending"

    }



    class MoviesListViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val repository: MoviesRepository, private val state: SavedStateHandle): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MoviesListViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return MoviesListViewModel(repository, state) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")

        }


    }



}
```

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't really describe what is happening. You could try deleting a load of code to understand better what is happening. You have 3 of everything, change this to 1 and see if its still "not working"

Comment: What do you mean three of everything? What's happening is that when I check the checkbox and go to another tab or fragment, the checkbox is unchecked. Also when I go to another tab and come back I'm at the top of the recyclerview, not where I last left off

Comment: You have moviesAction, moviesComedy etc etc etc, just simplify it all and get it working for 1 example

Comment: I have several fragments, each fragment displays different types of movies(action, comedy, etc). I'm trying to get it working on trending movies but it's not working

Comment: Yes, but nobody on stackoverflow has time to explore your whole app :-) and for yourself also, if you create a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it will help you and more likely get someone to answer your question (if you don't answer it yourself before hand)

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - "it's not working" is a useless description of a problem. Does that mean it crashes? It spins forever? It makes fart noises? It texted your ex "I miss you"?
Also "as you can see I'm trying to save the state of trending movies" - I don't see that because you have "save" and "get" methods that as far as I can see are never used.

Comment: It doesn't save the state. When I navigate back, the state is lost.

Comment: I'm not asking people to explore my app lol, I'm trying for now to save the state of the trending movies and when I figure out how I'll apply it to the rest